# ".*" regex duplicates output?

Tags: objective-c, regex

Code:

```
static NSString* regexReplace(NSString* regexString, NSString* subject, NSString* replacement)
{
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:0 error:nil];
    return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:subject options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length]) withTemplate:replacement];
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {

        NSLog(@"%@", regexReplace(@".*", @"foo", @"bar")); //Output: barbar
        NSLog(@"%@", regexReplace(@".+", @"foo", @"bar")); //Output: bar

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the ".*" regex replace 'foo' with 'barbar' instead of 'bar'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it matches twice: first it matches the `"foo"` part, and then it matches an empty `""` at the end of the `"foo"`.

(You can even imagine it matching an infinite number of times, yielding `"barbarbarbar..."`, but the regex engine is intentionally designed to produce only one empty-string match before moving on, exactly so as to avoid such infinite loops.)

Comment: Does any other regex engine do that? It just doesn't seem logical at all.

Comment: @Tyilo apparently yes.  I just tried http://www.regextester.com/ and got the same result.

Comment: Well, Perl, Java, JavaScript, and so on all do the same, though I don't know if they count as "other regex engines" (since their regex implementations are all very closely related). One regex engine that does *not* do this is that of `sed`; `sed 's/a*/b/g'` will map `x` to `bxb`, but `a` to just `b`, not `bb`. If there are other regex engines you're interested in, try them and see!

Comment: @PeterM I have apparently never tried replacing with ".*" before for testing. Doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: @ruakh I'm probably just failing again, but why doesn't this work as expected: `NSLog(@"%@", regexReplace(@"([^f]*)", @"foo", @"$1"));`

Comment: @Tyilo  Jon Skeet has had a say on this (he's everywhere) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985937/why-does-year-2010-0-4-results-in-empty-string-in-1  I think that this also answers your new question

Comment: @PeterM It prints `foo` not an empty string, and I would expect it to print `oo`

Comment: @Tyilo: The reason it prints `foo` is that it takes `foo`, replaces the `oo` with `oo` and an empty end-of-string string with the empty string, and returns the result. Nothing ever removed the `f`. If what you want is to filter out `f`s, you would write `regexReplace(@"f", @"foo", @"")`, which replaces `f`s with the empty string and leaves `o`s alone, producing `oo`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on ruakh's answer a bit is a similar SO question which gives more of a "why" answer:

[why-does-year-2010-0-4-results-in-empty-string-in-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985937/why-does-year-2010-0-4-results-in-empty-string-in-1)